# How to use hbw_malloc library within C++ program?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-management, resize

I would like to be able to allocate C++ object like Vectors directly on MCDRAM using the hbwmalloc library. The problem is that only C malloc are implemented. Thus I thought about coding a subclass of Vector implementing resize, reserve with dynamic allocation using hbw_malloc.

This would allow the programmer to choose the NUMA node on which allocate the data.

Is this the best idea to do what I want ?

Comment: Implement an `std::allocator` for the vector, see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [memkind library](http://memkind.github.io/memkind/) (which provides you an easy access to MCDRAM) already provides a C++ allocator for you. See this [manual entry](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man3/hbwallocator.3.html) for more information.

It's usage is quite simple, as shown in this example

```
#include <hbw_allocator.h>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
        std::vector<unsigned, hbw::allocator<unsigned> > v;
        v.push_back (123);
        assert(v.size() == 1);
        assert(v[0] == 123);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <hbwmalloc.h> // hbw_check_available, hbw_malloc, hbw_free
#include <cstddef>     // std::size_t
#include <cstdint>     // std::intptr_t
#include <stdexcept>   // std::logic_error
#include <new>         // std::bad_alloc
#include <memory>      // std::addressof

#define do_hbw_check_available

template <class T>
struct hbw_allocator
{
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::intptr_t;

    static pointer allocate(size_type n)
    {
#if defined(do_hbw_check_available)
        if (0 != hbw_check_available())
        {
            throw std::logic_error("HBW not available");
        }
#endif

        // Calculate size of storage with alignment and padding
        const size_type size = sizeof(value_type) * n;

        // Allocate storage
        pointer p = hbw_malloc(size);

        // Ensure that memory was in fact allocated
        if (nullptr == p)
        {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }

        return p;
    }

    static void deallocate(const_pointer p, size_type /* n */)
    {
        hbw_free(p);
    }

    void construct(pointer p, const_reference t)
    {
        // Call copy-constructor of the element pointed to by p
        new ((void*) p) value_type(t);
    }

    void destroy(pointer p)
    {
        // Call destructor of the element pointed to by p
        p->~value_type();
    }

    size_type max_size () const
    {
        return size_type(-1) / sizeof(value_type);
    }

    bool operator!=(const hbw_allocator<value_type>& arg) const
    {
        return !(*this == arg);
    }

    // Returns true if and only if storage allocated from *this can be deallocated from other, and vice versa.
    // Always returns true for stateless allocators.
    bool operator==(const hbw_allocator<value_type>& /* arg */) const
    {
        return true;
    }

    pointer adress(reference arg)
    {
        return std::addressof(arg);
    }

    const_pointer adress(const_reference arg) const
    {
        return std::addressof(arg);
    }

    template <class U>
    struct rebind
    {
        using other = hbw_allocator<U>;
    };
};
```

**Example:**

You then use it like:

```
template <class T>
using hbw_vector = std::vector<T, hbw_allocator<T>>;

hbw_vector<int> vec(5);
```